# Linux: How to know where a process was started and how it was started?

Tags: linux

I was checking a Linux box and found a perl process running and taking a good share of cpu usage. With top, i could only perl in process name.

When i pressed **c**, to view the command-line, it showed /var/spool/mail. Which does not make sense, since this is directory.

My questions are:

1) Why did this happen? How this perl process could mask its command-line?
2) What is the most reliable way of finding out where and how a process was started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In most cases just running `ps` is usually sufficient, along with your favorite flags to enable wide output.  I lean towards `ps -feww`, but the other suggestions here will work.  Note that if a program was started out of someone's `$PATH`, you're only going to see the executable name, not the full path.  For example, try this:

```
$ lftp &
$ ps -feww | grep ftp
lars      9600  9504  0 11:30 pts/10   00:00:00 lftp
lars      9620  9504  0 11:31 pts/10   00:00:00 grep ftp
```

It's important to note that the information visible in `ps` can be completely overwritten by the running program.  For example, this code:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
        memset(argv[0], ' ', strlen(argv[0]));
        strcpy(argv[0], "foobar");
        sleep(30);
        return(0);
}
```

If I compile this into a file called "myprogram" and run it:

```
$ gcc -o myprogram myprogram.c
$ ./myprogram &
[1] 10201
```

And then run `ps`, I'll see a different process name:

```
$ ps -f -p 10201
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
lars     10201  9734  0 11:37 pts/10   00:00:00 foobar
```

You can also look directly at `/proc/<pid>/exe`, which may be a symlink to the appropriate executable.  In the above example, this gives you much more useful information than `ps`:

```
$ls -l /proc/9600/exe
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 lars lars 0 Feb  8 11:31 /proc/9600/exe -> /usr/bin/lftp
```

Comment: all, in all, the files in `/proc` will provide all information about a program, `exe` will be a link to executable, `cwd` to current working directory, `fd` directory contains links to open files (including standard input, output and standard error)

Answer (score 85):

Most reliable way is to look at the `/proc` dir for the process. Each process has a `/proc/<pid>/` directory where it keeps information like:

1. `cwd` link to the current working directory
2. `fd` a dir with links to the open files (file descriptors)
3. `cmdline` read it to see what command line was used to start the process
4. `environ` the environment variables for that process
5. `root` a link to what the process considers it's root dir (it will be / unless chrooted)

There's more cool info on each process /proc, but with those above you will be able to exactly know what is going on.

Also, using `ps auxf` will show you who forked what so you may get a better idea who is calling your perl.

Comment: I always use Process Explorer on Windows and wondered if there was an equivalent on Linux. That switch does it all! ps auxf ... nice!

Comment: +1 for the f parameter for ps, that did it for me!

Comment: +1 for teaching me what seems like such a fundamental concept... `/proc` contains process information! who knew?? all i ever looked in there for was `version` and `cpuinfo` and stuff... plus this solves my actual problem because my router's version of ps ignores all parameters

Comment: @coredump : and if the process called`chroot()`before, how I can know which directory`/proc/ᴘɪᴅ/cwd`corresponds to ?

Answer (score 29):

for me, just now, i found that `pstree` gave a much clearer indication of how a process was started, than `ps aux`

it looks like this:

```
  ├─lightdm─┬─Xorg
  │         ├─lightdm─┬─init─┬─apache2───2*[apache2───26*[{apache2}]]
  │         │         │      ├─at-spi-bus-laun─┬─dbus-daemon
  │         │         │      │                 └─3*[{at-spi-bus-laun}]
  │         │         │      ├─at-spi2-registr───{at-spi2-registr}
  │         │         │      ├─dbus-daemon
  │         │         │      ├─dropbox───29*[{dropbox} ]
```

Comment: And in order to find what you're looking for easier, use `pstree | grep --color 'pattern\|$'`

Answer (score 14):

you can use:

```
systemctl status <PID>
```

or with the name of the process:

```
systemctl status $(pgrep perl)
```

This will deliver information on systemd services that started your process.

I found this hint [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225802/finding-systemd-unit-owning-a-running-daemon-process)

Comment: ... unless, of course, the process was _not_ started by `systemd`. After all, there are a lot of legacy services that may still sidestep `systemd`...

Answer (score 3):

Try `ps axww | grep perl` to get the full command line of your process. It looks like `top` just trimmed a long line.

Answer (score 2):

Wihtout consulting the man page for the exact flags, an easy way to fund out what the command line and the start time is,
ps auxwww
should work.
You can make it more elegant if desired by reading the man page.

Answer (score 2):

Try use command 
`fuser -vu /var/spool/mail`
This command will displays you the PIDs of processes using the specified files or file systems. In the default display mode, each file name is followed by a letter denoting the type of access:

c - current directory. 
e - executable being run. 
f - open file. f is omitted in default display mode. 
r - root directory. 
m - mmap'ed file or shared library.

Maybe it will help you to move forward your searching to answer you are looking for. I don't know if it helps you but maybe you will find out some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Two commands spring to mind:

1) get the start time for the process out of '**ps**'.

```
$ ps -ax -o pid,start,comm
  PID  STARTED COMMAND         USER
    1   Feb 06 init            root
    2   Feb 06 kthreadd        root
[...]
  13147 19:09:48 chrome          hcooper
  13270 19:13:51 chrome          hcooper
  13386 19:18:34 bash            hcooper
```

2) **lastcomm**, which now I check, I don't have installed. Anyhow the man page description says:

> ```
>    lastcomm prints out information about previously executed commands. If
>    no arguments are specified, lastcomm will print info about all of the
>    commands in acct (the record file).
> ```

But as a few people have said, "ls -al /proc/" will tell you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `PID` (process id), use `pstree` with `-s` (show parent processes) and `-p` (show PIDs):

```
$ pstree -sp 23419
systemd(1)───systemd(2339)───tmux: server(31195)───bash(23234)───sudo(23396)───apt-get(23398)───http(23419)
```

Then use `ps` to get the details of parent processes:

```
$ ps 23398 23396
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
23396 pts/4    S+     0:00 sudo apt-get update
23398 pts/4    S+     0:00 apt-get update
```