# Nginx cannot restart

Tags: nginx

I know about [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/842492/nginx-duplicate-listen-options-for-80-error) similar question, but I can't seem to fix my issue reading through it.

**Background**

I am trying to run [Chronograf](https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.8/) via Nginx. I already have a few Nginx block running.

For this one, I follow the example [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-5-%E2%80%93-setting-up-server-blocks-(recommended)), so I set up the following file in this location: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/chronograf.baseurl.com`:

```
server {
  server_name chronograf.baseurl.com www.chronograf.baseurl.com;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8888/;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Then I check the syntax with `sudo nginx -t` and see that all is good:

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Finally I run `sudo systemctl restart nginx` and get a failure:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The `/var/log/nginx/error.log` posts:

```
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [info] 4740#4740: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: still could not bind()
```

Can someone help me debug this?

**UPDATE 1**

As per the @Pandurang's suggestion:

1. I stopped `nginx` by running `sudo systemctl stop nginx`.
2. Then I run the `ps -ef | grep nginx` command.

It returns the following output:

```
root       846   821  0 Apr13 ?        00:45:11 runsv nginx
root       870   846  0 Apr13 ?        00:47:39 svlogd -tt /var/log/gitlab/nginx
stelian   3028  2943  0 15:47 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
root     32462   846  0 01:47 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx
gitlab-+ 32493 32462  0 01:47 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+ 32494 32462  0 01:47 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+ 32495 32462  0 01:47 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+ 32496 32462  0 01:47 ?        00:01:18 nginx: worker process
gitlab-+ 32497 32462  0 01:47 ?        00:00:00 nginx: cache manager process
```

I suspect there is a clash between nginx and GitLab?

Comment: kill Nginx process using `killall nginx` and test.

Comment: This yields: `nginx: no process found`. The `ps -ef | grep nginx` still yield the same as shown in my post above.

Comment: Start nginx process using systemctl start nginx command.

Comment: I cannot because it fails, due to the last update of the `chronograf.baseurl.com`.
I get `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`

Comment: I think you nginx process used by gitlab.could you please kill gitlab process and test

Comment: I killed the gitlab process and now nothing comes up when I do `ps -ef | grep nginx`

Comment: Start using systemctl start nginx command.Also share systemctl status nginx command output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108546/discussion-between-newskooler-and-pandurang).

Comment: use `sudo netstat -nap | grep nginx` to identify which ports the various nginx process are listening on

Answer (score 1):

```
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2020/05/27 02:22:27 [emerg] 4751#4751: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

The issue is that ports 80 and 443 are already in use somewhere: `Address already in use`

The next step in debugging is to identify what process is listening on (or 'bound to') the ports in question using `netstat` and `egrep`:

```
sudo netstat -nap | egrep ':(80|443)\s.*LISTEN'
```

(root privileges are required for `netstat -p`, which prints associated process information)

Here's an example where nginx is listening:

```
$ sudo netstat -nap | egrep ':(80|443)\s.*LISTEN'
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4498/nginx: worker  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4498/nginx: worker  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4498/nginx: worker  
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      4498/nginx: worker  
$
```

Comment: The result I see is:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32462/nginx: master `
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32462/nginx: master`

Comment: I am confused because nginx is stopped and disabled. Yet I still see it listening on the above ports and this still seems to be blocking me adding another nginx block and generally all feels quite tangled.

Comment: @Newskooler see https://serverfault.com/a/233250/296703

Answer (score 1):

use `netstat -an | grep :80` command to check whether the port is used by other services or not.

Comment: I see this when I run the command `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN   ` and the `PID/Program name` is `32462/nginx: master `

Comment: Looks like nginx process is running on 80 port. Stop nginx process using `systemctl stop nginx`  command. Make sure that Nginx process stopped using `ps -ef | grep nginx`. Then start Nginx process using `systemctl start nginx`. Also make sure that you are using single entry of listen 80 and listen 443 port.

Comment: can see my Update 1, please?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error recently, and the solution for me was that apache was also running at the same time. You can check this by

```
sudo systemctl status apache2
```

If it is running this command will stop it

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2
```

And this will prevent apache from running

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2
```

Comment: I don't have an `apache2` running though. `Unit apache2.service could not be found.`

Comment: I don't have enough karma to comment on your above question, but you could check what's listening on 80 by using this command `sudo netstat -lnp`.